# Store items of promises resolved

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Good afternoon,

I'm meeting a wall, in Parse Javascript, trying to store items after getting them in promise in loop. Outside the loop of pictures, the array of objects is void.

```
.. define global ** var filesUpload = []**

 for (var key in files) {
         var photoUpload = new Parse.File(String(file.name),[file.image])
             photoUpload.save().then(function(item) {
                    deferred.resolve(item)

                    filesUpload.push(deferred.promise)


             }, function(error) {
                console.log("error to save file"+JSON.stringify(error))
                // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
            })
         }
```

--> end loop

filesUpload is empty

Comment: Looks like you are trying to wrap a promise with another promise, which is not necessary.

Comment: Of course the array is empty right after the loop - promises are asynchronous. What else did you expect?

Comment: What is this `deferred` that you are resolving?

Comment: the deferred init $q.defer()

Comment: @aurny2420289: But where? Notice you're in a loop here. Btw, you should not mix Parse promises with jQuery deferreds.

Comment: You right @Bergi, my question concerning how to have the when all promise resolved and well answered just above Parse.Promise.when(..)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the values of multiple promises you'll have to use `Promise.all`. Now, `Parse.com` doesn't seem to have a `Promise.all` implementation but they do have something similar:

```
Parse.Promise.when(files.map(function(file){
    return new Parse.File(String(file.name),[file.image]).save();
})).then(function(){
    var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    //results === your filesUpload
}).then(null, function(err){
    console.log("error to save file" + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

If you prefer `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(files.map(function(file){
    return new Parse.File(String(file.name),[file.image]).save();
})).then(function(results){
    //results === your filesUpload
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("error to save file" + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

I also used `Promise.prototype.catch` which is not available either on the `Parse.Promise` implementation, most promises do implement this method though. ES6 Promises for example have both methods, `Promise.all` and `Promise.prototype.catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are asynchronous, which means that any code appearing immediately after your `for` loop, runs before the promise is resolved and the `then` function is called.

It's as if you did something like this:

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.write('inside setTimeout');
}, 1000);

document.write('after call to setTimeout');
```

Whatever you need to do with your `filesUpload`, you need to do it inside of the `then` callback of your `photoUpload.save()` promise. You can extract a function and call it from there.

```js
 for (var key in files) {
   var photoUpload = new Parse.File(String(file.name), [file.image])
   photoUpload.save().then(function(item) {
     deferred.resolve(item)

     filesUpload.push(deferred.promise)
     goAhead();

   }, function(error) {
     console.log("error to save file" + JSON.stringify(error))
       // The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
   })
 }

 function goAhead() {
   // go ahead
 }
```

Comment: Please don't use `document.write` in asynchronous functions, not even for demonstration

Comment: @Bergi - the behaviour of `document.write` inside of an async function is weird, as I just found out, but it does demonstrate my point here with a simple script.